# Port-forwarding on livebox to router

Tags: router, port-forwarding, netgear, livebox

At home, I have two routers, one Livebox and a Netgear. The reason why I need the Livebox is that the phone line cannot be connected to the Netgear router.

So I have the Livebox connected to the phone line, the Netgear connected to the Livebox, and all PCs connected to the Netgear.

My issue is that for every application or port that I want to give external access, I have to create entry in both the Livebox and the Netgear routers; so I would like to know if there's a way to automatically forward all requests to the Netgear router, from which I will then forward to the required IP:port.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Why use two routers? You can just use the netgear as a switch and only the livebox as the router for all pcs, then manage your Port Fwd from the livebox.

Anyway, to answer your question, it should be achievable. Unfortunately I am not familiar with the Livebox / Netgear interface, but on other routers I have seen Port Forwarding by range. You specify a range of ports and where you want them forwarded and that's it.

Comment: Ah, it's true that I did not think of that!! But I'm using one of the computers on the network as server (with Win 2008 R2), would that cause any problem? And then, there seems to be a limit to the number of entries for port-forwarding...

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem with the Windows server.
Suppose you forward port 80 to the Server and you want the first 2000 ports forwarded to Netgear, just specify 1-79 as the first range and 81-2000 as the second range. These are two separate entries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the livebox (only Inventel models i think) in bridge mode and then you'll be able to manage all your routing from your Netgear router. If you can't put the livebox in bridge mode then you'll have to redirect a wide port range to the Netgear router.

Comment: How do I achieve the bridge mode? Is there any general description you can give me please? Or is it specific to the router?